# Autofac IComponentContext.Resolve With Parameters

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

How would one provide an IComponentContext func to a type Registration where the parameters could be either types (to be resolved) or parameters passed in?

So if I have a func I'd like to use for registration such as this:

```
    public static ClassTarget Resolver(ClassArg1 arg1, ClassArg2 arg2)
    {
        // Do something fancier than this...
        return new ClassTarget(arg1, arg2);
    }
```

How would I register that for `ClassTarget`?

A full example, with the hack I'm currently using and alternate registration that work (as one would expect):

```
public class ClassArg1 { }

public class ClassArg2 { }

public class ClassTarget
{
    public ClassTarget(ClassArg1 arg1, ClassArg2 arg2) {  }
}

public static class ResolveFuncTest
{
    public static ClassTarget Resolver(ClassArg1 arg1, ClassArg2 arg2)
    {
        // Do something fancier than this...
        return new ClassTarget(arg1, arg2);
    }

    private static T GetArgValue<T>(IComponentContext componentContext, IEnumerable<Parameter> parameters)
    {
        if (parameters != null)
        {
            var param = parameters.OfType<TypedParameter>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Type == typeof(T));
            if (param != null)
            {
                return (T)param.Value;
            }
        }

        return componentContext.Resolve<T>();
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // The first argument will be resolved as normal
        builder.RegisterType<ClassArg1>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();

        // Works - just a typical type registration without the Func used
        //builder.RegisterType<ClassTarget>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();
        // Works - but only if we know how to resolve the arguments as types or parameters
        //builder.Register((c, p) => Resolver(c.Resolve<ClassArg1>(), p.TypedAs<ClassArg2>())).AsSelf().SingleInstance();
        // Works - smells though!
        builder.Register((c, p) => Resolver(GetArgValue<ClassArg1>(c,p), GetArgValue<ClassArg2>(c, p))).AsSelf().SingleInstance();

        // Build/scope
        var context = builder.Build();
        var scope = context.BeginLifetimeScope();

        // The second argument is passed as an instance/parameter at resolve time
        scope.Resolve<ClassTarget>(new TypedParameter(typeof(ClassArg2), new ClassArg2()));
    }
}
```

Clearly I misunderstand something core here, since I'm stumbling over myself to do the parameter resolution that Autofac normally does so seamlessly!  Is there just another overload to `Resolve` I'm missing in the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you have to do your initialization entirely inside that `Resolver` function, you are probably stuck using the mechanism you have now.** That is, if you have a specific function and, for whatever reason, you have to both instantiate the `ClassTarget` object *and* you have to initialize it there, you're stuck.

**If you can refactor a bit, you can use the [delegate factories](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html) feature of Autofac to your advantage.**

Here's an example of what the code could look like if you refactored a bit and used the delegate factory feature:

```
public class ClassArg1 { }

public class ClassArg2 { }

public class ClassTarget
{
  // Create a delegate factory with the set of parameters you require
  // during the Resolve operation - things that won't be auto-filled by Autofac.
  public delegate ClassTarget Factory(ClassArg2 arg2);

  // The constructor can have all the required parameters. Make sure the
  // names here match the names in the delegate factory.
  public ClassTarget(ClassArg1 arg1, ClassArg2 arg2)  { }

  // Just something to show the initalization working.
  public bool IsInitialized { get; set; }
}

public static class ResolveFuncTest
{
  public static void Initialize(ClassTarget target)
  {
    // Instead of newing up the ClassTarget here, let Autofac do that
    // through the delegate factory and *only* do initialization here -
    // the "something fancier" you previously alluded to.
    target.IsInitialized = true;
  }

  public static void Test()
  {
    // Register the argument that gets populated by Autofac.
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<ClassArg1>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();

    // Register the ClassTarget and Autofac will see the factory delegate.
    builder.RegisterType<ClassTarget>().OnActivated(args => Initialize(args.Instance));

    var context = builder.Build();
    using(var scope = context.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
      // Resolve a factory delegate rather than resolving the class directly.
      var factory = scope.Resolve<ClassTarget.Factory>();
      var classTarget = factory(new ClassArg2());

      // Do whatever you need.
      Console.WriteLine("ClassTarget is initialized? {0}", classTarget.IsInitialized);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm guessing this is a little closer to what you were hoping to achieve.

Comment: Point taken on the delegate factories - that definitely seems more Autofac-like.  What I was really hoping to achieve though, is to have Autofac resolve the func params regardless of it being a type or resolve parameter - basically remove the GetArgValue call - similar to if I didn't have the func at all and I was just using the class constructor (which I could, and admittedly probably should do here).  Is the delegate factory required when you're using an instance param to resolve (if you don't handle the IComponentContext form)?

Comment: For better or worse, Autofac is fairly well tied to reflection when it comes to automatically populating parameters in places - be they constructor params or properties to set. If you can use the constructor, just do it. You may also be interested in [the `Func<X, Y>` implicit relationship type](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#parameterized-instantiation-func-x-y-b).

Comment: The larger point is - try separating the instantiation of the object from the initialization. I'm guessing that the complex logic you have in the `Resolver` is more about initialization than instantiation. Let Autofac instantiate, then use an `OnActivated` handler or just the constructor to do the actual initialization.

Comment: Yeah, you're absolutely right, and really that's probably the core issue.  (Still working through it all to confirm with the other example.)

Comment: On the reflection point though, wouldn't it be similar logic as with the constructor?